# Page just blanks and loads forever when I press button

Tags: javascript, html, function, google-visualization

http://jsfiddle.net/iansan5653/7EPjH/17/

```html
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function chart() {
        var pressure;
        var temperature;
        var humidity;
        var url = 'http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=97c669df9c4795db96b39188000c1998&_render=json&lat=26.6403&lon=-81.8725';
        $.getJSON(url,
            function(data){
                pressure = data.value.items[0].data[1].parameters.pressure.value;
                temperature = data.value.items[0].data[1].parameters.temperature[0].value;
                humidity = data.value.items[0].data[1].parameters.humidity.value;
            }
        );
        
        google.load('visualization', '1', {
            packages: ['gauge']
        });
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
            
        function drawChart() {
        
            pressure = eval(pressure);
            var barData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Label', 'Value'],
                ['C/Precip', pressure]
                ]);
        
            var barOptions = {
                width: 400,
                redFrom: 28,
                redTo: 29,
                yellowFrom: 29,
                yellowTo: 30,
                greenFrom: 30,
                greenTo: 31,
                min: 28,
                max: 31,
                majorTicks: ["28","29","30","31"],
                minorTicks: 10
            };
        
            var barChart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('barometer_div'));
            barChart.draw(barData, barOptions);
            
            temperature = eval(temperature);
            var thermData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Label', 'Value'],
                ['Temp (F)', temperature]
                ]);
        
            var thermOptions = {
                width: 400,
                redFrom: 80,
                redTo: 120,
                yellowFrom: 0,
                yellowTo: 40,
                yellowColor: '0099FF',
                greenFrom: 40,
                greenTo: 80,
                min: 0,
                max: 120,
                majorTicks: ["0","10","20","30","40","50","60","70","80","90","100","110","120"],
                minorTicks: 10
            };
            var thermChart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('thermometer_div'));
            thermChart.draw(thermData, thermOptions);
       
            humidity = eval(humidity);
            var humidData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Label', 'Value'],
                ['Humidity', humidity]
                ]);
        
            var humidOptions = {
                width: 400,
                yellowFrom: 10,
                yellowTo: 40,
                greenFrom: 40,
                greenTo: 70,
                redColor: '0099FF',
                redFrom: 70,
                redTo: 100,
                min: 10,
                max: 100,
                majorTicks: ["10","20","30","40","50","60","70","80","90","100"],
                minorTicks: 10
            };
            var humidChart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('humidostat_div'));
            humidChart.draw(humidData, humidOptions);
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="chart()">Draw Chart</button>
    <div id='barometer_div'></div>
    <div id='thermometer_div'></div>
    <div id='humidostat_div'></div>
</body>
```

I managed to get the Google Charts code to work without being a function just fine, but when I wrap all the code in a function and try to call the function by pressing a button, the page just loads forever. I tried running JSLint to clean up the code, but it still didn't work. Also, the error console (I am using Firefox) doesn't give any errors or warnings. I just can't figure out why this is breaking.

Comment: seems google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart); is not firing lemme check out why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/7EPjH/26/) ... the `google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);` was never called so I added a callback function in the google.load:

```
google.load('visualization','1',{'packages':['gauge'],'callback':drawChart})
```

Comment: I'm on Chrome, did you see the JSFiddle I linked? does it work in there? what brawser you using? did you edit your code or used mine? http://jsfiddle.net/7EPjH/26/

Comment: looks like it works in your jsFiddle too... http://jsfiddle.net/7EPjH/27/ it takes a while at first, but it works... you have to write 'packages':['gauge'] you had packages:['gauge']

Comment: I'm using Firefox. Both of them are working on the first click, but when I click the button again, it breaks. It wasn't working for me before because I double-click a lot. Maybe it's the way the function is being called?

Comment: define it breaks, I see them gagues getting slightly bigger the more I click them...

Comment: how would you like it to behave on second click?

Comment: I would like it to refresh the gauges by loading them again, however, when I click it the second time, the gauges disappear and don't come back.

Comment: what about this: http://jsfiddle.net/7EPjH/28/ I just flush the divs content before override, looks good on my brawser... gonna make a your way solution w/o jQuery...

Comment: I see on second click it disappears, but looks they come back after clicking some times, is that right? It will be helpful trying to find a fix. http://jsfiddle.net/7EPjH/29/